# React hooks: why does useEffect need an exhaustive array of dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've got the following use case in a React component.

It is a search user input that uses [React Autosuggest](https://react-autosuggest.js.org/). Its value is always an ID, so I only have the user ID as a prop. Therefore at first load to show the username value, I need to fetch it at first mount.

EDIT: I don't want to fetch the value again when it changes later, because I already have the value from my suggestions request.

```
type InputUserProps = {
  userID?: string;
  onChange: (userID: string) => void;
};

// Input User is a controlled input
const InputUser: React.FC<InputUserProps> = (props) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.userID && !username) {
      fetchUsername(props.userID).then((username) => setUsername(username));
    }
  }, []);

  async function loadSuggestions(inputValue: string): Suggestion[] {
    return fetchSuggestions(inputValue);
  }

  function selectSuggestion(suggestion: Suggestion): void {
    props.onChange(suggestion.userID); // I don't want to rerun the effect from that change...
    setUsername(suggestion.username); // ...because I set the username here
  }

  return (
    <InputSuggest
      value={props.userID}
      label={username}
      onSuggestionsRequested={loadSuggestions}
      onSuggestionSelected={selectSuggestion}
    />
  );
};

export default InputUser;
```

(I'm adding a simplified way this component is called)

```
const App: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => {
    // simplified, I use react-hook-form in the real code
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState<string?>(any_initial_value_or_null);
    return <InputUser userID={userID} onChange={(newValue)=>setUserID(newValue)} />
};

export default App;
```

It works, but I have the following warning on my useEffect hook

```
React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'props.userID' and 'username'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
```

But if I do so, I will run it more than once as the username value is changed by the hook itself! As it works without all the dependencies, I'm wondering:

- How can I solve my case cleanly?
- What are those dependencies for and why is it advised to be exhaustive with them?

Comment: _I don't want to rerun the effect from that change_ - if i understand your updated question, you want the effect to run only once, so using an empty array is fine. Alternatively, you could include all the dependencies to the dependency array of the `useEffect` but only fetch the user on initial render using a condition that is evaluates to false after `useEffect` has executed at-least once.

Comment: Yes, I still get this eslint warning. But I guess that's just a too agressive rule that I should disable. `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'props.userID' and 'username'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`

Comment: I would advise against disabling this rule for the reasons mentioned in my answer and in the linked article. Lying about the dependencies is only OK in some particular cases like yours but generally you should include all the dependencies of the effect in the dependency array. Also try to improve the design of your app if you can, to avoid having to do this in the first place.

Comment: `useEffect` dep's array differ from other hooks like `useCallback` and `useMemo` that could cause stale values if every dep isnt included. `useEffect` relies more on business logic and therefore imo a linter shouldn't decide your business logic. for the most part I usually list all the deps if possible, otherwise I ignore the rule for that scenario and leave a comment as to why. `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `userId` should indeed be a dependency, since if it changes you want to run your query again.

I think you can drop the check for `username` and always fetch when, and only when the `userId` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(props.userID) {
        fetchUsername(props.userID)
            .then((username) => setUsername(username))
    }
}, [props.userID])
```

Generally speaking, you want to list all closure variables in your effect to avoid stale references when the effect is executed.

-- EDIT to address OP questions:
Since in your use case you know you only want to perform the action on the initial mount passing an empty dependency array is a valid approach.

Another option is to keep track of the fetched userID, e.g.

```
const fetchedIds = useRef(new Set())
```

whenever you fetch username for a new ID you can update the ref:

```
fetchedIds.current.add(newId)
```

and in your effect you can test:

```
if (props.userID && !fetchedIds.current.has(props.userID)) {
   // do the fetch
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I would have done. But getting a warning from the eslint react rules set tells me that something is wrong with that. I even get autofixed when I run eslint --fix !

Comment: notice that I removed the dependency on `username`  - what error are you getting using the code in my answer?

Comment: You're right, I get no error. However, when I select a suggestion - it will trigger onChange, set a new props.userID and fetch the username again (which I already have from the suggestions request).
I just edited my post with a more exhaustive example, sorry for not having done it before ;-)

Comment: please add the code that changes the `userID` as well, I'm not sure I/m following you

Comment: The user ID is a controlled input, so it takes a value and an onChange callback. I will edit my post

Answer (score 2):

> What are those depdendencies?

`useEffect` takes an optional second argument which is an array of dependencies. Dependencies of the `useEffect` hook tell it to run the effect whenever one if its dependency changes.

If you don't pass an optional second argument to useEffect hook, it will execute every time the component re-renders. Empty dependency array specifies that you want to run the effect only once, after the initial render of the component. In this case, `useEffect` hook will almost behave like componentDidMount in class components.

> why is it advised to be exhaustive on them ?

Effects see `props` and `state` from the render they were defined in. So when you use something from the scope of functional component that participates in react's data flow like props or state, inside the callback function of `useEffect` hook, that callback function function will close over that data and unless new effect is defined with the new values of props and state, your effect will see the stale props and state values.

Following code snippet demonstrates what could go wrong if you lie about the dependencies of `useEffect` hook.

In the following code snippet, there are two components, `App` and `User`. `App` component has three buttons and maintains the id of the user which is displayed by the `User` component. User id is passed as a prop from `App` to `User` component and `User` component  fetches the user with the id, passed as prop, from the `jsonplaceholder` API.

Now the problem in the following code snippet is that it doesn't works correctly. Reason is that it lies about the dependency of the `useEffect` hook. `useEffect` hook depends on `userID` prop to fetch the user from the API but as i skipped adding `userID` as a dependency, `useEffect` hook doesn't executes every time `userID` prop changes.

```js
function User({userID}) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (userID > 0) {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userID}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => setUser(user))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
    }
  }, []); 
  
  return (
    <div>
      {user ? <h1>{ user.name }</h1> : <p>No user to show</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [userID, setUserID] = React.useState(0);
  
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setUserID(id);
  };
  
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>User with ID: 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(2)}>User with ID: 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(3)}>User with ID: 3</button>
      <p>Current User ID: {userID}</p>
      <hr/>
      <User userID={userID} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Above code snippet shows one of the few problems that could arise if you lie about the dependencies and this is why **you must not skip or lie about the dependencies** of the `useEffect` hook or any other hook that has a dependency array, for example `useCallback` hook.'

**To fix the previous code snippet**, you just have to add `userID` as a dependency to the dependency array of `useEffect` hook so that if executes whenever `userID` prop changes and new user is fetched with the id equal to `userID` prop.

```js
function User({userID}) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (userID > 0) {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${userID}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(user => setUser(user))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.message));
    }
  }, [userID]); 
  
  return (
    <div>
      {user ? <h1>{ user.name }</h1> : <p>No user to show</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [userID, setUserID] = React.useState(0);
  
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setUserID(id);
  };
  
  return(
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(1)}>User with ID: 1</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(2)}>User with ID: 2</button>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick(3)}>User with ID: 3</button>
      <p>Current User ID: {userID}</p>
      <hr/>
      <User userID={userID} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In your case, if you skip adding `props.userID` in the dependency array of `useEffect` hook, your effect will not fetch the new data when the prop `userID` changes.

To learn more about the negative impacts of omitting the dependencies of `useEffect` hook, see:

- [Don’t Lie to React About Dependencies](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#dont-lie-to-react-about-dependencies)

> How can I solve my case cleanly ?

Since your effect depends on the prop value `userID`, you should include it in the dependency array to always fetch the new data whenever the `userID` changes.

Adding `props.userID` as a dependency to `useEffect` hook will trigger the effect every time `props.userID` changes but the problem is that you are unnecessarily using `username` inside the `useEffect`. You should remove it because that is not needed since `username` value doesn't and shouldn't decide when new user data should be fetched. You just want the effect to run whenever `props.userID` changes.

You could also decouple the action from the state update by using the `useReducer` hook to manage and update the state.

#### Edit

Since you only want to run the effect even when `userID` is used by `useEffect` hook, in your case it is ok to have an empty array as the second argument and ignore the eslint warning. You could also not omit any dependencies of the `useEffect` hook and use some condition in `useEffect` hook that evaluates to false after the effect runs for the first time and updates the state.

Personally i would suggest you to try to change how your components are structured so that you don't have to deal with this kind of problem in the first place.

Comment: Your comment was very helpful but would you please take a look at this too? I'm trying to understand why useEffect doesn't use the lexical scope to read the updated value? And how could I can create the very same stale closure scenario without using the useEffect? Thanks..

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil callback function of the `useEffect` has a closure over the surrounding scope; it only sees the values from the scope in which it was defined. This behavior is not specific to React and `useEffect`; this is how all javascript function's behave. "_And how could I can create the very same stale closure scenario without using the useEffect?_" - whenever you create a function in javascript, it has a closure over the surrounding scope; [here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-worker-ymo83) a simple example.

Comment: "callback function of the useEffect has a closure over the surrounding scope" - A function closes over its surrounding scope **and also inherits the lexical scopes of its parent functions** and in doing so creating a *scope chain*. So shouldn't the variable in the render method also falls in the lexical scope chain of an effect's callback? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil _"and also inherits the lexical scopes of its parent functions"_ - in the case of `useEffect` hook's callback function, react component is the parent function and its scope is what the callback function of the `useEffect` hook closes over. When a component re-renders, that is actually react calling your component again which creates a new scope; this new scope has no link to the scope which was created when the component is called for the first time. See the code example I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. So what is happening is that react calls my component again which creates a new scope; also the effect callback is being **cached** in the `useEffect`. And because the **cached callback** has a lexical scope chain of the older scope, this creates the whole stale-closure scenario. If there hadn't any caching logic in the `useEffect`, this would not have been produced . Am I saying it right?

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil Until the `useEffect` hook executes again, setting a new callback function which has a closure over the new component scope, previously set callback of the `useEffect` hook will continue to log the stale state or prop values that it closed over in the older scope.

Comment: Great, I got it. Thank you so much. Would you be kind enough to post this as an answer too on my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545371/how-to-create-a-stale-closure-like-the-one-in-reacts-useeffect-hook-without-usi)?

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that before mounting the InputUser component, all dependent props have been filled and they have the right value, then add `eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` right before `}, [])` line, but If depended props have no value at first component mounting, So you have to add them in useEffect dependencies.

Comment: That rule is authored by the react core team, so my point is more that if it yells - something is probably wrong with my design. That was more the point of my question ;-)