# How to create a stale closure like the one in React's useEffect hook without using the actual useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures

I know how closures work but I'm failed to understand how a **stale closure** gets create in a React's `useEffect` in the absence of an exhaustive dependencies array. To do so, I'm trying to replicate a stale closure just like in React's `useEffect` without using the `useEffect`, but I'm unable to create it. My code doesn't create a stale closure and instead logs a correct value on every interval. Could you please take a look at the snippet below and tell me:

1. What am I doing wrong? What should I do to create a stale closure like the one we get in React's `useEffect` when we don't provide the complete dependencies array? *(reference code is at the end of the post)*
2. Why does a stale closure is created when we don't give exhaustive dependencies in a useEffect? Why doesn't the code in a `useEffect` hook's callback just use the lexical scope, like a normal function would, and print the actual value?

```js
function createIncrement(incBy) {
  let value = 0;

  function increment() {
    value += incBy;
    console.log(value);
  }
  
  function useEffect(fun) {
    fun()
  }
  
  useEffect(function() {
    setInterval(function log() {
          // what should I do to create a stale closure here?
          // So that if I change the value it should show me the old value
          // as it does when using React's useEffect without exhaustive dependencies array

          console.log(`Count is: ${value}`); // prints correct value each time
        }, 2000);
  });
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    increment(); // increments to 5
    increment(); // increments to 6
  }, 5000);
  
  return [increment];
}

const [increment] = createIncrement(1);
increment(); // increments to 1
increment(); // increments to 2
increment(); // increments to 3
increment(); // increments to 4
```

For completeness sake, below is a code snippet using React's useEffect where we don't provide an exhaustive dependency array to React's useEffect and hence a stale closure is created:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function WatchCount() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(function () {
    setInterval(function log() {
      // No matter how many times you increase the counter 
      // by pressing the button below,
      // this will always log count as 0
      console.log(`Count is: ${count}`);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increase</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<WatchCount />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong? What should I do to create a stale closure like
> the one we get in React's useEffect when we don't provide the complete
> dependencies array?

You don't get a stale closure because you call the `createIncrement` function only once.

In order to re-render a functional react component, react calls the component function again. This creates a new scope which has no link to the scope created in the previous call to the function component.

To get a stale closure, you need to call `createIncrement` more than once.

```js
function createIncrement(incBy, functionCallIdentifier, intervalDelay) {
  let value = 0;

  function increment() {
    value += incBy;
    console.log("inside call: " + functionCallIdentifier + " - value: " + value);
  }

  increment();
  
  function useEffect(fun) {
    fun();
  }

  useEffect(function () {
    setInterval(function log() {
      console.log("inside call: " + functionCallIdentifier + " - count: " + value);
    }, intervalDelay);
  });
}

createIncrement(1, "first call", 2000);

// calling again but 'setInterval' set in the first call will continue
// to log the latest value of variable "value" that it closed over, i.e. 1 
createIncrement(2, "second call", 4000);
```

> Why does a stale closure is created when we don't give exhaustive
> dependencies in a useEffect? Why doesn't the code in a useEffect
> hook's callback just use the lexical scope, like a normal function
> would, and print the actual value?

The above code example should give you an idea of why the stale closure gets created. `useEffect`'s callback function indeed uses the lexical scope but the difference is that calling the function component again creates a new scope but the old callback function of the `useEffect` hook set in the previous render of the component will continue to see the values from the scope in which it was created.

This behavior is not specific to react - this is how every function in javascript behaves: each function closes over the scope in which it is created.

Until the previous callback is cleared before setting the new callback in the `useEffect` hook, old callback will continue to log the values from the scope that it closed over.

Following code example uses a clean up function to clear the interval set in the first call to the `createIncrement` function.

```js
function createIncrement(incBy, functionCallIdentifier, useEffectCleanupFn) {
  if (useEffectCleanupFn) {
    useEffectCleanupFn();
  }

  let value = 0;

  function increment() {
    value += incBy;
    console.log("inside call: " + functionCallIdentifier + " - value: " + value);
  }

  increment();
  
  let cleanupFn;

  function useEffect(fun) {
    cleanupFn = fun();
  }

  useEffect(function () {
    let id = setInterval(function log() {
      console.log("inside call: " + functionCallIdentifier + " - count: " + value);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
  });

  return cleanupFn;
}

let cleanupFn1 = createIncrement(1, "first call");

setTimeout(() => {
  createIncrement(2, "second call", cleanupFn1);
}, 4000);
```